# Outputting List<int[]> does not work

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out why my code isn't outputting the coin change permutations list as a list of int arrays. It's outputting some hex value (or whatever `I@64578ceb` is).

Any thoughts?

**Call:**

```
System.out.println("Permutations List: " + dan.makeChange(27));
```

**Code:**

```
public class Person {
int[] denominations, coinValues;
List<int[]> resultsList;

public Person() {
    denominations = new int[]{25, 10, 5, 1};
    resultsList = new ArrayList<int[]>();
}


public List<int[]> makeChange(int change) {
   return resultsList= changeMaker(change, new int[] {0,0,0,0});
}

public List<int[]> changeMaker(int change, int[] toAdd) {               
    if (change == 0) {
        resultsList.add(toAdd);
        return resultsList;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < denominations.length; i++) {
        if (change >= denominations[i]) {
            int[] temp = toAdd;
            temp[i]++;
            resultsList = changeMaker(change-denominations[i], temp);
        }
    }
    return resultsList;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Permutations List: [[I@64578ceb, [I@64578ceb, [I@64578ceb, [I@64578ceb, [I@64578ceb, [I@64578ceb, etc...
```

Comment: Arrays don't have a readable `toString()` they just print the hashCode. You probably need to write your own method to print it nicely.

Comment: Why are you mixing Collections and primitive arrays? You can use a `List<List<int>>`.

Comment: Try `Arrays.toString(dan.makeChange(27))` instead

Comment: @EvanMulawski except that this is Java, not C#, so `List<List<Integer>>`.

Answer (score 4):

`int[]` doesn't have pretty `toString()` for you to display numbers, You need to write your own method to accept `int[]` and print in whatever format you want

Comment: Maybe use `Arrays.toString`? Of course, this might/not fit the intentions of OP but its a valid way and a built in pretty printer.

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println method doesn't know how to print arrays in any type.

In case you want to display int array, build a function that takes an int[] and return string, and then wrap every entry at the List with that function when you printing it out.

Answer (score 0):

That's how arrays are printed in Java. You need to loop and "pretty-print" the arrays yourself with `Arrays.toString()`:

```
List<String> printable = new ArrayList<> ();
for (int[] array : list) {
    printable.add(Arrays.toString(array));
}
System.out.println(printable);
```

Answer (score 0):

`[I@64578ceb` is the printed representation of an `int[]`.  Your permutations list is a list of `int[]`, so you're seeing the elements of the list surrounded by `[` and `]`, and the elements, each of which looks something like `[I@64578ceb`.  For a very quick and dirty solution, you could use the `List.toArray` method and `Arrays.deepToString` to get a string representation of your list of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

To print the content of an array either iterate over each element in the array:

```
int[] array = new int[10];

for(int s : array) System.out.println(s);
// or
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) System.out.println(array[i]);
```

or use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5b%5d%29):

```
int[] array = new int[10];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

which will print something like:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

> It's outputting some hex value (or whatever I@64578ceb is).

Let me explain the following simple example:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
System.out.println(array);
```

`array` is an object, hence you are calling [`println(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) of [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) (`System.out`), which calls `toString()` on the passed object internally. The array's `toString()` is similar to [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)'s [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

```
getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

So the output would be something like:

```
[I@756a7c99
```

where `[` represnts the depth of the array, and `I` refers to `int`. `756a7c99` is the value returned from [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) as a hex number.

Read also [`Class.getName()` JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29).

Comment: for loops to iterate through each element produces same result